# What does ばだった stand for?

Tags: grammar

What is the meaning and the grammar behind ばだった?

Here is the sentence I've found it in:

> このほか、経済的な理由で、キャンプや海水浴などを体験させることができないと答えた保護者の割合が、「困窮層」では２０％台後半から４０％台半**ばだった**のに対し、「一般層」は１％未満と大きな開きが見られました。

Comment: http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/163317/meaning/m0u/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

40%台半ば + だった。
It was about 45%.

Answer (score 0):

A large disparity was observed: as against the fact that the proportion of carers in the "impoverished" category who answered that for economic reasons they were unable to give [the children in their care] the experience of camping or sea-bathing was from the upper 20% range to the mid-40%  [40%半ば]range, the proportion in the "average" category was less than 1%.
That is, of the categories studied, 25% to 45% of those classified as "poor" said they couldn't afford to send the kids in their charge to camp or take them to the seaside, while less than 1% of those classed as "average" or "ordinary" said this.
40%なかば = "mid-forty-per-cents"